# Deeplinking in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to deep link my app with website and for that I tried two ways:

```
 <meta property = 'al:ios:url'  content = "realagent://chats"/>
 <meta property = 'al:android:url'  content = "realagent://chats"/>
 <meta property = 'al:android:package' content = "com.application.xyz"/>
```

and

```
window.location = 'yourapp://app.com/?screen=xxxxx';
```

But neither work for me. I tried the first one and it doesn't even work on a single platform, but second one works on Android.

Please help me with this, and suggest the correct way?

Comment: You want deep linking from web url to open your app?

Comment: yes @YorkShen-MSFT

Comment: What's your Android `MainActivity`'s `IntentFilter`?

Comment: [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataScheme = "AvalpayApps", DataHost = "*")]

Comment: You could read this document : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49341/unable-to-get-applinks-with-rivets-component-working-on-android

Comment: And this : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59165/dynamic-deep-linking-from-web-url-to-open-mobile-application

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT let me read them